# How to give link to Button without changing button-shape?

Tags: extjs4

I trying to create button in extJs 4 .But due to adding property href and hrefTarget its changing its shape.What should I have to do give link to my Button without making my button as anchor tag ? Actualy I want to open new tab on button click..

```
        var startButton = Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
                text:'Start',
                id: 'startButton',
                href : 'http://www.google.com',
                hrefTarget: '_blank',
                baseCls:'deviceAuthenticationButtonCls button-link',
                handler : function() {                                          
                                        console.log(Ext.getCmp('startButton'));
                                        console.log("Form ",form.getForm().getValues());
                                        form.getForm().setValues([
                                                                   {id:'First', value: "0006660767C7"},
                                                                   {id:'Second', value: "00066607644D"}
                                                                   ]);
                                        var data = form.getForm().getValues();
                                        console.log("Data To Send :- ",data);
                                        form.getForm().submit({
                                            url: './mmaGlove/',
                                            method:'POST', 
                                            params : {
                                                deviceAuthenticationData: JSON.stringify(data)

                                            },
                                            success: function(){                                                                                                        
                                                window.location = "http://www.google.com";                                                                                                                                          
                                            },
                                            failure : function(){
                                                alert('Got Error..');
                                            }
                                        });                                 
                }

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can redirect in the function handler:

```
function() { window.location = "http://www.sencha.com" }
```

... for instance. In this case you don't set the href propety so the button doesn't become an `<a></a>` label.